¿Por qué no puedo abrir eL archivo java con netbeans desde la carpeta de origen?
Cuando intento abrir el archivo java con netbeans desde la carpeta de origen me aparece para abrirlo con otras IDE que tengo instaladas, como Intellij IDEA y visual studio code pero cuando eligo netbeans me aparece la opcion de desintalar el mismo netbeans, no entiendo porqué pasa eso.

Tienes netbeans bien instalado? Puedes ejecutarlo normalmente? Una vez abierto "normal" puedes elegir abrir el proyecto que mencionas? Tienes permisos para usar el programa? Tienes permisos para acceder a la carpeta? Tienes el acceso de netbeans en el menú contextual bien puesto? Cómo lo has puesto? Qué SO usas? Está actualizado? Versión de NetBeans? Como no pongas todos los detalles esto va a ser imposible. Las preguntas deben dar todos los detalles necesarios para poder dar una respuesta, no decir "esto no me va, por qué?". Utiliza el enlace [edit] y añade los detalles.

Uff, abrir un .java desde la carpeta de origen... ¿No es eso demasiado incómodo? ¿Vas metiéndote en la carpera "src", luego en la "main", luego en la "java"... etc.? Me parece mucho más sencillo abrir Netbeans, y desde ahí abrir el proyecto en la carpeta raíz que vas a tener el archivo abierto igual y además vas a tener a mano el resto de archivos del proyecto. Es un poco raro trabajar en un solo archivo y si solo usas un archivo ¿necesitas Nebeans? A lo mejor un editor avanzado como Notepad++ te sirve.

Parece que el .exe para abrir netbeans desde el menú "abrir con" del archivo no esta bien seleccionado. Se podría cambiar seleccionando manualmente el .exe correcto desde la opción "abrir con" del archivo. Aún así sería mas recomendable que cargaras la carpeta entera del proyecto en Netbeans y trabajaras con ella así.
